# mesos slaves are fluctuating periodically in the mesos master web UI

Tags: mesos

i have 1 mesos master and 3 mesos slaves installed in linux mint environments. now when i run all the masters and slaves i could see in the mesos master that each of the slaves are appearing periodically in a timely manner. I could not able to see all 3 slaves appearing on the mesos UI page.

my question is Is it normal or I should be able to see all three slaves together?
 I have downloaded the mesos form apache mesos site and created mesos master and slaves manually.

EDIT:

here is my master/state.json deails:

```
  {"activated_slaves":0,"build_date":"2015-08-12 18:18:29","build_time":1439417909,"build_user":"root","completed_frameworks":[],"deactivated_slaves":1,"elected_time":1439426147.74133,"flags":{"allocation_interval":"1secs","allocator":"HierarchicalDRF","authenticate":"false","authenticate_slaves":"false","authenticators":"crammd5","framework_sorter":"drf","help":"false","initialize_driver_logging":"true","ip":"ip address","log_auto_initialize":"true","logbufsecs":"0","logging_level":"INFO","max_slave_ping_timeouts":"5","port":"5050","quiet":"false","recovery_slave_removal_limit":"100%","registry":"replicated_log","registry_fetch_timeout":"1mins","registry_store_timeout":"5secs","registry_strict":"false","root_submissions":"true","slave_ping_timeout":"15secs","slave_reregister_timeout":"10mins","user_sorter":"drf","version":"false","webui_dir":"\/mesos-0.23.0\/build\/..\/src\/webui","work_dir":"\/var\/lib\/mesos","zk_session_timeout":"10secs"},"frameworks":[],"hostname":"school_name.ip.in-addr.arpa","id":"20150812-203547-1316479616-5050-10790","leader":"master@ip:5050","orphan_tasks":[],"pid":"master@ip:5050","slaves":[{"active":false,"attributes":{},"hostname":"name","id":"20150812-203547-1316479616-5050-10790-S4930","offered_resources":{"cpus":0,"disk":0,"mem":0},"pid":"slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051","registered_time":1439475605.91917,"reserved_resources":{},"resources":{"cpus":8,"disk":901526,"mem":31022,"ports":"[31000-32000]"},"unreserved_resources":{"cpus":8,"disk":901526,"mem":31022,"ports":"[31000-32000]"},"used_resources":{"cpus":0,"disk":0,"mem":0}}],"start_time":1439426147.73525,"unregistered_frameworks":[],"version":"0.23.0"}
```

here are few details that could help you guys to understand the installation:
i have downloaded meses from apache site and locally build and run them.from master i run the mesos-mster as

```
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=128.226.119.78 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

and from slaves i have run mesos slaves as

```
./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=128.226.119.78:5050
```

I did the same from all 3 slaves.

here are two console output that i could see in the slave machines appearing again and again continiously.

```
Querying resource estimator for oversubscribable resources
I0813 10:29:18.962781  9900 slave.cpp:4193] Received oversubscribable resources  from the resource estimator
```

Comment: It seems abnormal, could you show me the result of your cluster 'http://your_master_ip:your_master_port/master/state.json' ?

Comment: Can you share the logs from the slaves?

Comment: While you're preparing the logs, is the Mesos Master able to open a connection to mesos slaves? Can you ping slave nodes from the master node?

Comment: haosdent: i have added the master state json file

Comment: Dharmit: one observation , i coulld see slaves are getting registered newly every time, so seems like master can not hold more than one slaves. Is there any config for letting master know about available slaves?

Answer (score 0):

from the master state.json. I found you need set a ip when start slave.

```
slaves:
   [ { active: false,
       attributes: {},
       hostname: 'gladiator',
       id: '20150812-203547-1316479616-5050-10790-S4930',
       offered_resources: [Object],
       pid: 'slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051',
       registered_time: 1439475605.91917,
       reserved_resources: {},
       resources: [Object],
       unreserved_resources: [Object],
       used_resources: [Object] } ],
```

The slave start and listen to 127.0.0.1, so the master could not connect it correctly. You could try

```
./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=128.226.119.78:5050 --ip=your_slave_ip_which_could_connect_from_master:5051
```